# What is it called when an argumentative yes-or-no question has different meanings depending on the answer?

Tags: sociolinguistics, discourse-analysis, questions

I'm wondering if there's a word for this specific type of informal fallacy.

An example of such a question is "Do black lives matter?", where the questioner specifies the literalness of the question after you give your answer. So if you answer "no", the questioner will assume the literal meaning of the question, and accuse you of saying the lives of black people are not important, but if you answer "yes", they will assume a more figurative meaning of the question, and take it as affirmation that you are a supporter of Black Lives Matter, a specific political movement.

My best guesses are a loaded question or a double-barreled question. It could be a loaded question in that it presupposes only two possible options, you can either be a racist or an antiracist and nothing else. It could also be a double-barreled question in that it is two questions in one, the literal and figurative, but I'm not sure it counts as a double-barreled question since it's not a compound sentence (it does not contain an "and"), and it only assumes one meaning at a time rather than both at once. Maybe there's a word for a kind of double-barreled question where only one of the the two possible meanings of the question is selected after an answer is given?

Comment: There's nothing in the question itself that makes it special in a way and different from other yes/no questions, it's all about the context, the _intention_ of the ones who ask, and the way they _interpret_ the answer and _manipulate_ it. In fact, any question can be made provocative and any of your answers can be interpreted against you. Note that before the Black Lives Matter political movement appeared, that very sentence couldn't have been used that way. For a person tied to a chair and being tortured, it is rather problematic what to answer to the torturer's question “Are you OK?”

Comment: @YellowSky the question is special because it's an informal fallacy, at least in the way it's used in the hypothetical scenario I give. Forcing a choice between being racist or antiracist is certainly a false dilemma. Maybe that's all it is.

Comment: Ok maybe the question isn't anything special but the claim that "You don't support the BLM movement therefore you are a racist." is a false dilemma. That's what was confusing me.